# CRUDRepository native query with parameter

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using a native query in spring data JpaRepository like below :

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.email, '@', -1) as domain, COUNT(*) as domainCount r.invite_organization_id"
        + "  FROM users u,_registrations r where u.user_id=r.user_id and r.invite_organization_id=?1"
        + "  GROUP BY "
        + "SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.email, '@', -1) ORDER BY domainCount DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> countTopDomain(String orgId);
```

The above gives me the following exception :
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r.invite_organization_id  FROM users u,registrations r where u.user' at line 1

How will I pass the value for invite_organization_id(in the query ) from the method countTopDomain() argument.

Comment: countTopDomain(@Pram("orgId") String orgId) and :orgId instead of ?1 inside query

Comment: I am getting the below error even after changes according to you : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r.invite_organization_id  FROM srs_users u,srs_user_registrations r where u.user' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

'r.invite_organization_id FROM srs_users u,srs_user_registrations r', have syntax error. ',' is missing after count (*) as domainCount

Comment: You should format your answers using the code segments

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.email, '@', -1) as domain, COUNT(*) as domainCount, r.invite_organization_id"
    + "  FROM srs_users u,srs_user_registrations r where u.user_id=r.user_id and r.invite_organization_id=?1"
    + "  GROUP BY "
    + "SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.email, '@', -1) ORDER BY domainCount DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> countTopDomain(String orgId);
```